# Left half of the screen is moved to the right, right half is partially moved left and distorted, video card related issue?

Tags: display, graphics-card, motherboard

Since yesterday, after about an hour the left half of my screen is moved to the right on my display, and the right half is moved to the left, and has weird flickering lines. Also since today there's a weird line on top of the screen that also flickers.

This is a pretty vague description, so this is a photo of my monitor:
[image: Image showing the issue]

Now this issue happened yesterday with a Windows 8 installation, and after a clean OS install today again with a Windows 7 installation.

In order to try and diagnose the problem, I've used a different monitor, and a different cable. I'm thinking this has something to do with the video card. After a reboot, the issue is temporarily gone.

Taking a screenshot with print screen doesn't reproduce this issue.

Video card: AMD Radeon Sapphire HD6950 Dual Fan 1GB GDDR5 PCI-E.
Motherboard: Asrock 870 Extreme3 R2.0.

After my clean installation I've installed the latest (non-beta) AMD Catalyst Control Center, and some other drivers (LAN, sound, USB3, input devices, etc. nothing special). For the rest the only software installed is .NET Framework 4.5, Visual Studio 2012, Paint.NET, and two games with the latest DirectX, nothing special either.

If it is any help at all, I have been noticing rather frequent IO freezes. Where during the spinning up of my disc drive and sometimes at other times my entire computer would freeze, and I wouldn't be able to do anything except tasks that only require the CPU for approximately 40 seconds. I am quite certain this has to do with the motherboard, which is a component which has been causing issues since the start. (Not booting up, not being able to read from the hard drive, even though they're in perfect shape.)

I'm wondering if anybody knows of ways to diagnose where the actual problem is, or even better, if there are any solutions for this problem. I've tried searching the internet but didn't find anything useful.